# I'm a beginner and write console programs I'm trying to build a calculator and need help (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to know how to use a user input similar to `Convert.ToInt64(Console.Readline())` but if they type e.g.: 198.98

Into the floating point type you prefer var doesn't work I don't know what else to do

Comment: You need to explore something like [long.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64`, as the name _might suggest_, always tries to `convert` something `to` an `Int64`. it could _never_ return a floating point value.  
welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:

```
float.TryParse(Console.Readline());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this method instead of using the Convert class. If you want to make sure your program doesn't throw an exception, try `float.TryParse()` instead.

```
var f = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(f);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the input parameter and then try to cast it.
use try parse to cast

```
    if(double.TryParse(request.Code, out var doubleNumber))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

read this doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

We have various options for performing this conversion. The difference between float and double is that float has four places after the decimal point and double has twelve places after the decimal point. So of you want double you can use it as,

var num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())

In case if you want to convert it into float we have two options there, parse and tryparse. Parse returns the converted number and TryParse returns the Boolean value of conversion. You can use it accordingly like,

var num = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

Answer (score 0):

try this one:
for your situation you have to use below code:

```
Convert.ToDouble(Console.Readline());
```